# Android not able to post in facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

Hi i implemented facebook api in my project .. I followed this tutorial [enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

```
String url="https://www.google.co.in";

   Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("description","I just scored:"+bestscore);
        postParams.putString("link", url);




    facebook.dialog(this, "feed",postParams, new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

            /*logoutFromFacebook();

            logout();*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {


            /*
            logout();*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            //logout();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //logout();
        }
    });
```

Everything its working fine...  if i changed that url like **https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.m2f.christmascandysmash** ... Its showing error like this. if url its short means its working fine(like.. www.facebook.com) [image].

After long search i found that problem with url link.. but same thing works fine before 2 months. How to fix this issue ?

Comment: One thing is not clear to me. Why you provide URL over here?

Comment: from fb .. user/friends can click link and directly download from that link

Comment: @JohnRaja, try my below solution and let me know whether it is working or not?

Comment: temporarily i found solution.. instead on direct link  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.m2f.christmascandysmash .. i seach in google christamscandysmash and placed that link https://play.google.com/store/search?q=christmascandysmash%20mobi2fun&c=apps . Now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I don;t know whether it will work or not but just give a try.

Go to the Facebook App. Edit its settings. On the Advanced settings page, disable the "Stream post URL security" option.

How to go.

Go to [developers.facebook.com/apps](http://developers.facebook.com/apps) On the left hand side, click your app to select it.

Next to the "Settings" section in the middle column, there's an "Edit Settings" link.

Click that. On the new page, under the "Settings" menu on the left hand side, click "Advanced".

Under the "Migrations" section, find "Stream post URL security". Set it to "Disabled". Click the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the screen..

It will look something like this

[image]

You can see by default this is on just click it OFF and click on Save Changes and then try to clean your project and run it again. Might be this will help you.

Comment: thanks. .done all but not able to find "Stream post URL security"  in advance setting

Comment: Check once again it is there, i have posted snap also.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the users to download you app if they press on your share on facebook, you should use facebook deep linking. May be they are making pattern of the url to prevent you from share google play store url using this way. Read about facebook deep link. This may be helpful for you.